# How can I add .Lib files to eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, lib

I am trying to attach libraries to my project, I on Eclipse, and I am using Microsoft Visual C++ compiler in it, and programming with C++.

I tried to attach the `.lib` files (you know properties -> settings ... normal adding), but when I build the project, it gives me errors, I tried to do something, but didn't work it gave me Binary Not Found...

How can I add `.lib` files to my project with Eclipse, I've googled all things I know, please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean _"normal adding"_? Did you set the library search path accordingly?

Comment: If you are using MSVC++, why would you not use Visual Studio, which is a far superior C++ development environment?

Comment: @user0042 I think I did, please tell me how to do it, so I can make sure I did it right !

Comment: @NeilButterworth I've already made everything there, so it's kinda annoying to move there, but if there's no way to add the libs, then I'll have no choice ?